# show only 10 items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I want to display top 10 items in recyclerView because the firebase database contains around 100 items and it would be really helpful if it showed 10 items

```
public class RankingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView name,coins;
    public ImageView profileimg;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public RankingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        coins=itemView.findViewById(R.id.coins);
        profileimg=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageprofile1);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      itemClickListener.onRecyclerViewItemClicked(view,getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `getItemCount()` method of the Adapter class to return 10.

Your RecyclerView then will only show the first 10 items.

Comment: how  to make getItemCount() method in this adapter

Comment: how to make this method @Anandroid

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
adapter.submitList(ItemList.subList(0,10))
```